# Show that if $f\in L^p$, then there is a Ball $B$ such that $\sup_{x\not\in B}|f(x)|<\varepsilon$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space, $B_r:=\{x\in E:\left\|x\right\|_E<r\}$ for $r>0$, $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathcal B(E)$ with $\mu(E)=\infty$, $p\in[1,\infty)$ and $f\in\mathcal L^p(\mu)$.

> Are we able to show that $$\forall\varepsilon>0:\exists r>0:\sup_{x\in E\setminus B_r}\left|f(x)\right|<\varepsilon\tag1?$$

Maybe we can show that, more generally, if $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ is any measure space and $\mathcal B\subseteq\mathcal E$ is any system containing a sequence $(B_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal B$ with $B_1\subseteq B_2\subseteq\cdots$ and $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n=E$, then $$\forall\varepsilon>0:\exists B\in\mathcal B:\sup_{x\in E\setminus B}\left|f(x)\right|<\varepsilon\tag2.$$

The idea is clearly to  use that $\mu(B_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\mu(E)=\infty$. Moreover, we would somehow need to bound $\left\|f\right\|_{L^p(\mu)}^p$ from below by something which tends to $\infty$.

Comment: An L^p function can be 1 on some unbounded set of measure 0, so this won’t be true. You need to replace supremum with essential supremum

Comment: @JonathanHole False even with essup.

Comment: @JonathanHole Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3936134/47771.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is false. Take $\mu$ to be Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$, $p=1$ and $f=\sum_n n \chi_{(n, n+\frac 1  {n^{3}})}$.

Comment: $nc\chi$ is a typo for $n\chi$???

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, but some non-zero $c$ wouldn't hurt -:)

Comment: What I've tried to generalize is the following simple observation: If $g\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, then $\langle 1_{[n,\:n+1]},g\rangle\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$. The idea being that if we "move the interval $[n,n+1]$ far enough to the right an integrable $g$ must eventually vanish". How can we formalize and generalize this?

Comment: Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3936134/47771.